# GQL example for server side admin console query with reference property filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

How to construct a GQL query using server side admin datastore viewer, a one that filters on a reference property?

```
SELECT * from Model where reference_property = <what goes here>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [GQL reference](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html). You can use `KEY('encoded key')` or `KEY('kind', 'name or id', ...)`.

Comment: Thx mate, shame on on me. 

I am starring on this reference pages for hour's daily and and it's getting blurry :)